# Intent, error in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I got an error in "intent code"

RegFragment.java :

```
public class RegFragment extends Fragment {

EditText text1,text2,text3;
Button btn1;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reg_layout, container, false);
    text1 = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    text2 = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
    text3 = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text3);

    btn1  = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new klik());       

    return rootView;         
}

class klik implements Button.OnClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent i=new Intent(this,Form1.class);  ------> ERROR...
        finish();
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: finish() is called after startActivity. Its called to finish current activity.

Comment: Form1 class is activity or what?It should be activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Form1.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
```

Please check  that your destination activity i.e Form1.class should be register in Manifest.xml file

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
 Intent i=new Intent(getActivity(),Form1.class);
```

`this` does not refer to activity context. `getActivity` returns the activity this fragment is associated with.

Use

```
 getActivity().finish();
```

Comment: it work sir...thank's 
but can you explain it for me....
and then theris still error in code "finsih();"

Comment: @user2467583 finish is also a method of activity class.

Comment: @user2467583 use `getActivity().finish();`

Answer (score 0):

do this..

```
Intent i=new Intent(getActivity(),Form1.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace **this** by **getActivity()**  for context in fragments.

Comment: not always. what about this `button.setOnClickListener(this)` ?

Comment: @Ketan sorry not always, I apologize